# Link to a specific spot on a page I can't edit

Tags: html

I'm looking to create a URL to a certain paragraph on an existing web page.
However I don't manage the web site I want to link to, so I can't add any anchors in its HTML code.

Is there any way to direct a URL to a specific HTML tag?
Kind of like JavaScript's `document.getElementsByTagName()[n]`.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong as this would be *really* helpful. Good question!

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: If the element you want to link to has no ID or named anchor then you're out of luck

Comment: Another short answer: for the same doman: kinda. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016995/540955