# Navigation Bar Complete- How to link pages?

Tags: html, css, navigation

So I'm very new to coding so forgive me if I'm not making sense. I completed my navigation bar, now, how do I add content when the user clicks on "About" "Gallery" "Resume" and "Contact" page? I have researched everywhere but no one seems to talk about the obvious next step? Would this next step still use HTML and CSS or is it now Javascript?

Would I create a separate html file for every page (About, Gallery, Resume, Contact) and add the information to each file then link it to the main index.html file?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can do this in pure html, using a `<a href="about.html">` (for about page) tag and it will take you to the page you link to with a refreshment in browser, JS  let you remove the page refreshment but it is an extra layer that you don't need to understand the basics

Comment: Could you please add the code you already have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a new html page for About, Gallery, etc.

Then you can use:

```
<a href="/SomeFolder/About.html">About Page</a>
```

to navigate to that page.

Note that /SomeFolder/About.html is that path of you about page. / means that we start from root folder.

Have a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems I was on the right path of how to attempt it- this makes me so proud! Haha, thanks for the layout!

Comment: How would you then link to a specific section in that page? e.g. `#About-Me`

Comment: @LV98: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481911/linking-to-a-specific-part-of-a-web-page) would help

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to a new world.

Yeah you have to create page for each(About, Gallery, Resume, Contact) with it own content with Html and Css, javascript is optional at this early stage.

Example:

```
<a href="about.html"> About </a>
<a href="gallery.html"> Gallery</a>
<a href="resume.html"> Resume</a>
<a href="contact.html"> Contact Us </a>
```

You can learn more on this website https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now! :) And thanks for welcoming me into this new world! I'm having fun and hope to learn a lot more! I'm creating my first website for a friend to hopefully start building a portfolio.

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to use an `a` tag like this `<a href="/about"></a>`