# Can I use full page tabs to create a navigation bar for my website?

Tags: html, css, menu, tabs, navigationbar

I'm new to coding and just learned basic techniques of HTML and CSS, not started JS yet. I want to create a three-tab nav bar on top. The first tab is some forms for visitors to fill out, the second tab is the list of the profile of registered people, of course, you can search and review the profile, the number could be thousands or more; the third tab is just plain text. Can I use the full page tabs below to structure it?
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_full_page_tabs.asp
what about using separate HTML links to each tab/menu as I read thru the discussion below? what's the difference? looks like they are quite different techniques.
[How can I reuse a navigation bar on multiple pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/how-can-i-reuse-a-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages)
[Navigation Bar Complete- How to link pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137553/navigation-bar-complete-how-to-link-pages)

Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_topnav)

you need to simply replace # with your links / PageName

```
 <a href=#"">FirstTap</a>
 <a href=#"">SecondTap</a>
 <a href=#"">ThirdTap</a>
```