# How to link to a page part without a URL fragment?

Tags: url, web-applications, url-fragment

I need to add links to a web application that point to specific parts of another page in the same application.

Normally, it is done using a URL with a fragment part (an element ID after the '#' character).
Unfortunately, the application has already used the fragment part of URLs to store another data - a kind of session ID.

I wonder if there is any other, reasonable way of pointing to a web page part, different than the URL fragments.

Comment: You can use javascript, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016995/3348617). It's a nasty solution, but I don't think you can avoid that when hashes in the URL is not an option.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now trying to modify the usage of hashes to be more universal, like query-style: #something=value&part=an_id_to_scroll_to. Then some javascript to parse and use it on  the target page. However, the inline javascript is also something woth thinking about.