# How to navigate to a particular div on the same page in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have to navigate to a particular div on the same page in React JS application. For example how it is being done in the following website. When one clicks on < NavLink > the UI scrolls and focuses on the particular div and similarly for other Links on this website. 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/strict-bool

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481911/linking-to-a-specific-part-of-a-web-page

Comment: I just want the focus to go to the particular div or components when I click on the side menu.

Comment: Google for "javascript scroll to specific part of page"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the offset of the target element and use `window.scrollTo` to position it either on top of the page or where ever you want. This would work in chrome/latest browsers. You might want to check for other browser compatibility.

```
let offsetTop  = document.getElementById("yourelement").offsetTop;
window.scrollTo({
    top: offsetTop-100, 
    behavior: "smooth"
});
```

**Program is in codepen** https://codepen.io/Divine1/pen/zbQVwR

**Update**

i have added this logic into a online reactjs project editor and it works.
You can see how this code works https://repl.it/@Divine1/QuietHeartyApplicationstack

Check `App.js` `App.css` and the live result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe is a better aproach to use useRef hook. on click is almost the same:

```
const ref = useRef();

// the function when you want to scroll:
() => window.scrollTo({
    top: ref.current.offsetTop -100, 
    behavior: "smooth"
})

// Where you want to go
<div ref={ref} />
```