# how do i create a link to redirect to a specific section of the same web page?

Tags: html, css

I tried doing that by creating a  tag at the desired section and then linking to that section using an anchor link but it doesn't work when i add a base url in the head element of the html document.
can someone explain me why it doesn't work on adding a base tag in the head element of the html document and is there any way i can have a base tag and still redirect to the desired section of the web page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking to a specific part of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481911/linking-to-a-specific-part-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

You use anchor tag with href to the id to element as shown below.

```html
<div id="sectionYouWantToLink">


<!-- Various Section Childs -->


</div>


<a href="#sectionYouWantToLink">Go To Section</a>
```

Now when you click the a tag > Go To Section, it will take you the specific section.

Comment: this isnt working when i have a base tag in the head element.

Answer (score -1):

Give an ID to your section and then use anchor tag and in it's hierarchical reference attribute write the id of the section to which you wish to refer. e.g.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
```