# How can i create a bookmark in my php code

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, href, bookmarks

i have create a bookmarke in a php code like this:

```
    echo "<a name ='Start'></a>";
```

I had create a hyperlink to this bookmarks with the following code

```
echo "<th colspan='3'><a href ='#Start'><font color='black'>Jump to start</a></th>";
```

But it dosn't work...

Whats wrong?

Everyone thanks for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking to a specific part of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481911/linking-to-a-specific-part-of-a-web-page)

Comment: What doesn't work? have you enough content between target and link to get page scrolling? Your code is more or less valid, so it does work. juest tested with `echo "start<br><a name ='Start'></a>";
for ($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) echo 'foo<br>';
echo "'<a href ='#Start'><font color='black'>Jump to start</a>'";`

Comment: BTW `<font>` tag is kinda oldschool and [depreciated in HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp), use CSS styling instead

Comment: `name ='Start'` is the old way. Use an ID instead. `id='Start'`